# How to get the value from a Text Input (a component) to my main app?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, native

I have my main app with a Text, a Text Input (a component) and a button (another component):

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Alert } from 'react-native';
import { Tinput } from './components/Tinput.js';
import { Button } from './components/Button.js';

      export default function App() {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text style={{fontSize:20, padding:20, textAlign:'center'}}>Ingrese un numero del pokémon a buscar!</Text>
          <Tinput/>
          <Button onPress={()=> ConsultarPokemon(/*this is where i want to insert the value from Tinput */)}> 
            Ingresar 
          </Button> 
          <StatusBar style="auto" />
        </View>
      );
    }
```

And this is my component Tinput, which has the text input:

```
import React from 'react';
import { TextInput } from 'react-native';

const Tinput = () => {
  const [numero, setNumero] = React.useState('');

  return (
    <TextInput
      style={{ width:'90%', height: 50, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1, backgroundColor: '#fffff0', textAlign:'center', borderRadius: 20, borderWidth:5, margin:20}}
      onChangeText={(value) => setNumero({numero: value})}
      value={this.state.numero}
      maxLength={20}
    />
  );
}

export { Tinput };
```

I want to use the value from the text input on my onPress function, I tried doing this but didn't work:

```
 <Button onPress={()=> ConsultarPokemon(Tinput.state.numero)}> 
        Ingresar 
 </Button>
```

Also, there's an error on my Tinput component: **undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.state.numero')**
So I'm probably using state the wrong way too

Comment: You can't acces another components state like that. You can only access your own component state or have acces to the state of a component higher in the tree. So the solution would be to move the state in the component that uses both of the components.

Comment: so i would have to give app a state of number for example, and then on my Tinput component change the state of app? and how would i access that state? app.setNumber({number:value}) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will use this.state.X only if you created classes like component classes , and here is an exemple :

```
    class Counter extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.initialCount = props.initialCount || 0;
        this.state = {
          count: this.initialCount
        }
      }
increment() {
    this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 })
  }
  reset() {
    this.setState({ count: this.initialCount})
  }
  render() {
    const { count } = this.state;
    return (
      <>
        <button onClick={this.increment.bind(this)}>+1</button>
        <button onClick={this.reset.bind(this)}>Reset</button>
        <p>Count: {count}</p>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

I suggest to do not complicate things and just handle onPress inside Tinput

```
    const Tinput = () => {
      const [numero, setNumero] = React.useState('');
    
      return (
    <View>
        <TextInput
          style={{ width:'90%', height: 50, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1, backgroundColor: '#fffff0', textAlign:'center', borderRadius: 20, borderWidth:5, margin:20}}
          onChangeText={(value) => setNumero(value)}
          value={numero} // no need to use this.state.numero
          maxLength={20}
        />
 <Button onPress={()=> ConsultarPokemon(numero)}> 
        Ingresar 
  </Button> 
 </View>
      );
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah i shouldnt have made it into a component

Comment: hey sorry to bother you again, i put the Text Input on my main app, so its not a component anymore. But its not taking the value i insert. The numero state works fine when i initiate it in the begining, but then (value) => setNumero ({ numero: value }) doesnt use then input i insert when i type. And... is it necessary to use the value = {numero} ? because it only shows on the screen what my numero is at the beginning (if i do initiate the numero state)

Comment: i updated my answer just replaced setNumero ({ numero: value }) with  setNumero (value)